# Android programmatically created button onClick from class

Tags: android, onclicklistener, programmatically-created

I have an `onClick` switch method in **MainActivity.java** and the buttons are programmatically created in **Navigation.java**. The initial menu `nav.mainMenu()` gets called correctly and the button is created as expected. My issue is that when I click the button, nothing happens.

I get no error stack trace in the logcat. I have tried putting logs in the onclick method, but it doesn't get that far. The emulator appears to work and does not freeze or crash.

I assume that when I send the code to the menu, the activity is in that class? so when I try to use the `onClickListener` in `MainActivity`, it isn't aware of it?

I'm also not sure what I should be expecting from `v.getId()` in **MainActivity.java** `R.id.btnGame`?

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

  public Navigation nav = new Navigation(this);

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.empty);
    nav.mainMenu();
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()) {
      case R.id.btnGame:
        nav.game();
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

**Navigation.java**

```
public class Navigation {

  Button btnGame;

  Context mContext;
  Navigation(Context mContext) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
  }

  public void mainMenu() {
    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(mContext);
    ll.removeAllViews();
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams llP = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    ll.setLayoutParams(llP);
    ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams btnParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    btnGame = new Button(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    btnGame.setLayoutParams(btnParams);
    btnGame.setText("Play Game");
    ll.addView(btnGame);

  Activity activity = (Activity) mContext;
    activity.setContentView(ll);
  }

  public void game() {
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "I dont see this", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
}
```

- I have tried adding `.setOnClickListener()` to the buttons in **Navigation.java** but I can't get the context right, I don't know if that's what is missing.
- Extending **Navigation.java** to MainActivity or Activity gives me a loop of errors.

**Logcat after the app has been built onto the emulator:**

```
09-30 17:43:59.655 7038-7038/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
09-30 17:43:59.655 7038-7038/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
09-30 17:43:59.854 7038-7038/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle-2/lib/x86
09-30 17:43:59.867 7038-7038/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
09-30 17:44:00.230 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
09-30 17:44:00.230 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
09-30 17:44:00.230 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
09-30 17:44:00.230 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
09-30 17:44:00.234 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9baa38c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
09-30 17:44:00.241 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9baa38c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99a887d0)
09-30 17:44:00.293 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9baa38c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99a887d0)
09-30 17:44:00.400 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9baa38c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99a887d0)
09-30 17:44:00.460 7038-7066/com.fomtirth.barcodebattle D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9baa38c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x99a887d0)
```

Comment: What errors? Can you show them?

Comment: I don't get any errors, the logcat is empty after the build. I will edit above to include the build output.

Comment: Have you filtered out the errors?

Comment: No, that was on `verbose`.

Comment: Well, I am fairly certain that the Context should be null there, however your button isn't doing anything because you seem to be missing a setOnClickListener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a Context from a field. You probably "can't assign a right", because you're actually getting a nullpointerexception and editing the wrong location. That being said, `getApplicationContext()` isn't needed.

Also, might I suggest that you return the content layout rather than casting the context to an Activity?

```
public Navigation nav;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  nav = new Navigation(this);
  setContentView(nav.mainMenu());

} 

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
  switch(v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnGame:
      nav.game();
      break;
  }
}
```

At first glance, I see that you never set a click listener on the button, so you should probably do that.

For example

```
Context mContext;
View.OnClickListener mClickListener;

Navigation(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    if (context instanceof View.OnClickListener) {
        this.mClickListener = (View.OnClickListener) context ;
    } 
}
```

Now use this

```
if (mClickListener!=null) {
    button.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
}
```

> I'm also not sure what I should be expecting from v.getId() in MainActivity.java R.id.btnGame?

The ID doesn't match the variable name. Without explicitly giving the button an ID, it'll be `-1`

Comment: I had tried moving the class definition into the onCreate method but I didn't think that was the issue as the initial menu call was still made. I've moved it and see no difference.
I have removed `getApplicationContext()`. So now I leave it as `btnGame = new Button(mContext);`? I get no response from this either.

Comment: That's brilliant. I couldn't work out how to add a `clickListener` to the button!

Comment: Your listener can be implemented wherever you need it. You can also add a setOnClickListener method to your Navigation class

Comment: Logging the view from the `onClick` method in MainActivity I get `-1` ? I'll log out the listener and see if I can work out what i've done wrong.

Comment: `v.getId()` is negative one because you never set the ID onto the button... Any reason you aren't using XML? You apparently already have some XML resources generating id values

Comment: If I use xml, I would have 6 additional layouts. I was hoping to make it a little cleaner with a class to build those 'pages'. 
Annoyingly, I had solved this before but didn't push the source anywhere when I formatted.

I have a number of `ids` created in in `R.values`. The only one I have set in a layout xml file is for the `LinearLayout`.

and finally.. `btnGame.setId(R.id.btnGame);` has solved everything! thank you very much!